# Problema al actualizar registro base de datos - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy actualizando el estado de un pedido, pero no se porque no consigo actualizar el registro, he hecho distintos formulario de edición, por ejemplo para editar un usuario y sin ningún tipo de problemas, pero aquí no hay forma, a ver si veis vosotros donde fallo.

Tengo una tabla que me arroja todos los resultados de los pedidos agrupados por un campo `idpedido`. En cada fila tengo un botón para poder ver el pedido, donde le paso por parámetro el `idpedido` para poder verlo. La ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('admin/pedidos/ver_pedido/{idpedido}', 'AdminController@verPedido')->name('admin.ver_pedido');
```

Dentro de la ficha del pedido tengo un botón con un formulario para poder editar una columna del pedido.

```
@if ($numPedido->estado == 1 && $numPedido->factura == null)
   <form action="{{ route('admin.editarEstadoPedido', $numPedido->idpedido) }}" method="POST">
      @method('put')
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="idpedido" value="{{$numPedido->idpedido}}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn facturar">Facturar</button>
   </form>
@endif
```

El `if` lo que hace es si el pedido esta sin facturar me aparece el botón, y si esta ya facturado no aparece.

Aquí la ruta para actualizar el pedido:

```
Route::put('admin/pedidos/{idpedido}', 'AdminController@editarEstadoPedido')->name('admin.editarEstadoPedido');
```

Y el controlador para actualizar:

```
public function editarEstadoPedido(Request $idpedido)
    {
        $tt = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('idpedido', '=', $idpedido)
            ->update([
                'factura' => '4234234'
             ]);
        $tt->save();

        return redirect('admin/pedidos');
    }
```

Por el momento le estoy pasando este valor `4234234` una vez me funcione ya generare lo que necesito. Hay que tener en cuenta que puede tener más de una fila el mismo `número de pedido`. Y bien me devuelve este error.

> Call to a member function save() on int

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el formulario en el action debes de enviarle el id del pedido no el campo idpedido

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.editarEstadoPedido', $numPedido->idpedido) }}"
```

y tu archivo de rutas

```
Route::put('admin/pedidos/{idpedido}', 'AdminController@editarEstadoPedido')->name('admin.editarEstadoPedido');
```

Como haces un metodo update en laravel del otro lado recibes dos cosas el Request y el idpedido

```
public function editarEstadoPedido(Request $request, $idpedido )
    {
   $idpedidoarr = Array($request->idpedido);
       //sabiendo que tienes un modelo de ORDER
       DB::update('update orders set idpedido = '. $idpedido .' where idpedido = ?', $idpedidoarr );

        return back();
    }
```

Con la intencion de que sigues correctamente y aprovechas al maximo laravel e construido o reconstrontruido la funcion

Comment: Pero aquí esta comparando el `id` autoincrementable, ese no es el que quiero comprobar @Dohko19 . Una pregunta, puede actualizar el registro y quedarse en la misma pagina?

Comment: Solo harías un return back(); y  es raro lo que pides ya que el Idpedido y siempre se busca por la PK y solo actualizas el campo que quieres

Comment: Piensa que al ser pedidos si piden más de una cosa se generan distintas filas, entonces están agrupados por un idpedido

Comment: Entonces tu base de datos esta mal y deberias de hacer una relacion hasToMany para dichos pedidos, ya que si un pedido con diferentes cosas no deberias generar mas filas dentro de pedidos, sino una tabla aparte

Comment: Desconocia hacerlo de este modo que me comentas, seria interesante saberlo para proximos proyectos, este esta llegando a su fin

Comment: entonces con modificare la pregunta para intentar realizar lo que necesitas, pruebas y me dices si te funciona

Comment: ya actualize la respuesta

Comment: Me devuelve esto @Dohko19  `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in`

Comment: Solo hay que tranformar ese request a un array

Comment: edite la pregunta o puedes poner al final $request->all()

Comment: Me devuelve esto `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'T' in 'field list' (SQL: update orders set idpedido = T-202010000 where idpedido = T-202010000)` pero hay algo que no entiendo, aquí no estoy modificado la columna `factura``

Comment: idpedido es lo que trae de tu forumario, puedes corroborar con `dd($idpedido)` antes de realizar todo proceso

Comment: Pero entonces faltaria donde modificamos la columna `factura`. Yo lo solucione de esta forma, que no es correcta?? `$tt = DB::table('orders')->where('idpedido', $request->input('idpedido')) ->update([ 'factura' => '4234234' ]);`

Comment: la factura siempre sera la misma?

Comment: Ese número se lo puse para realizar la prueba y funciona, el número de factura sera diferente según el pedido, si el pedido trae más de una fila si sera el mismo. Ahora mismo así como te digo me funciona bien, que no es correcto?

Comment: es correcto si te funciona, pero te funcionara si trae la misma factura varios campos?  a mi paracer lo hara solo una vez

Comment: Si hice la prueba de hacer un pedido con 3 articulos, me crea tres filas y me añade el número de factura en los tres

Answer (score 0):

La operación de base de datos lo estas haciendo a través del query builder. Cuando estas haciendo un update por esta via, no existe el metodo save. Al momento de llamar el update, esta va ejecutar la operación.

Comment: Hola @Philippe Thiers entonces entiendo que tengo que quitar `$tt->save();` si es así probe ya, no me devuelve error pero no hace cambios

Comment: puede que tu where de la query esten mal implementadas las condiciones, solo supongo que se llame id en vez de idpedido la columna en la DB

Comment: No estoy comparando el autoincrementable estoy comparando con otra columna que se llama idpedido

Comment: me indicas la estructura de la tabla para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Te subi una captura! puede que no pueda comparar si no es una columna `INT`

Comment: no debería ser el caso

Comment: Creo que lo tengo por lo que sea no recibia bien la variable `idpedido` hice un `request` y lo compare con este valor -> `->where('idpedido', $request->input('idpedido'))` y así si que encuentra resultados y modifica correctamente

Comment: Si es eso, igual en la funcion puedes hacer esto, `public function editarEstadoPedido(Request $request, $idPedido)` y utilizar el idPedido para la condicion de la query